# Is a val property thread-safety?

Tags: kotlin

I can use Code A to change the value of val a .

In my mind that val property is thread-safe, but it seems that it's not thread -safe in Code A,
it's just like var property, any thread can change the variable aImpl, different thread maybe get different value of `val a`

**Code A**

```
var aImpl = 0
val a: Int get() = aImpl

fun seta(){
    aImpl=5
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course not. It will work as a dynamic getter for `aImpl`, not as property.

And `aImpl` isn't `@Volatile`, so there is no any guarantees of thread-safety.

Comment: @s1m0nw1 In this concreate example it could be. No caching → no unpredictable effects.

Answer (score 3):

You fail to make a clear distinction between a `val` with and without a custom getter. If you lump those two together, like in your question, then `val` is not thread-safe; however Kotlin does make this distinction, as you can observe in this example:

```
val simpleVal: Int? = 3
val customVal: Int? get() = simpleVal

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    if (simpleVal != null) {
        println(simpleVal + 1)
    }

    if (customVal != null) {
        println(customVal + 1) // ERROR!
    }
}
```

> Error:(12, 21) Kotlin: Smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'customVal' is a property that has open or custom getter

The smart cast is not allowed, among other reasons, due to the potential of another thread mutating the result of the custom `get()` call.

Therefore:

1. A simple `val` is thread-safe;
2. A `val` with a custom or open getter is not (necessarily) thread-safe.